# Why google plus description is not sharing on click?

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

I want to share my google plus description. I am using Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.7.1.
No doubt it is making the meta decription tags but on clicking the description is not shared properly why ?
[image]

```html
<a class="social-is social-googleplus" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=" onclick="gplus=window.open(this.href+escape(window.location),
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,height=300,width=600');return false;" target="_blank"></a>
```

**What will be the issue ? Is my HTML Code true or there is something new ?**

Answer (score 0):

I was using og image with size 200x200. I used the image of size 600x600 and my problem resolved now.